# What to use as redshift_conn_id for Airflow RedshiftToS3Operator with cross account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, amazon-redshift

I am writing an Airflow job to unload query results from Redshift to S3 bucket at another party. I have the cross accounts set up to assume roles.

The `redshift_conn_id` I currently use is formatted as `aws://serviceaccount:password@redshift_endpoint/database`.

The error I got when running the job is:

> SyntaxError: conflicting or redundant options

What should I use as `redshift_conn_id` for `RedshiftToS3Operator`?

Answer (score 0):

`redshift_conn_id` is a reference to a specific Redshift database as per [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/_api/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/transfers/redshift_to_s3/index.html) & [source code](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/_modules/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/transfers/redshift_to_s3.html#RedshiftToS3Operator). It defaults to `redshift_default`.

Try using just `database` from your current `redshift_conn_id`.

Comment: Thank you! When using just `database`, I get error `psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: No such files or directory`